# How to prevent widget from restarting app activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I'm working on an Android application which includes a widget.

The main task of the widget (after clicking it by user) is to start Activity (`UpdateWidgetActivity`), which gathers data from server and update widget views.

This activity doesn't display any other views, so user (after clicking on widget) still should stay on home screen.

The problem is following:

- The user launch app (by clicking the icon) (for example Activity A)
- He presses Home button>
- He clicks on widget
- Widget runs `UpdateWidgetActivity` but Activity A is also restarted and shown to the user (which I don't want)

#### My question is

How to prevent app activity (Activity A) to be restarted when a user clicks on Widget, in order to perform completely different Activity?

I've seen a lot of similar topics here, but solution proposed there doesn't work in my app.

#### Here is the code of Widget Provider `onUpdate()` method:

```
{       
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetUpdateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_view, pendingIntent);
        
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
    }
}
```

I'm new here and actually I have only a basic knowledge of Android, so sorry for any mistakes or inaccuracy.